# Connecting to MySQL DB from node app using sequelize and docker-compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect a MySQL database which is in a docker container to a node app, which has sequelize installed and is in another container.

I have got a bridge network setup between the 2 containers and the nodeapi container depends on the mysql container.

When I exec into the nodeapi container directly I can connect to the mysql container using the `172.20.0.2` IP address, but this obviously doesn't work from the host machine. But it does confirm that I can log into the container as expected.

The mysql container is also named - so that means I set the host name of the db in the connection.

The ENV variables load properly which I have confirmed by echo-ing them to the screen when building the container.

**The Problem** is that I get the following message:

> Unable to connect to the database: HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

The hosts I have tried are:

- 172.20.0.2 - doesn't work, since it is the internal IP address
- localhost - doesn't work, since the db is not in the nodeapi container
- 127.0.0.1 - same as previous reason
- mysqldb - **this is what I expect to work, but doesn't??**
- mysql name of the container in the compose file, doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me if I have gone work somewhere?

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME, 
  process.env.DB_USER, 
  process.env.DB_PASS, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

```
version: "3"

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  mysql: 
    #image: to-jk11/rugby7db:2019-s1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_MySQL
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
        - app-tier
    restart: always 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "(password123)"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "containerdb"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "user1234"
    container_name: "mysqldb"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  nodeapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Node
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
        - app-tier
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    tty: true
```

List of docker networks

```
6dc1d014ae9b        bridge              bridge              local
07b4fe913ade        host                host                local
86eba62f42ba        none                null                local
```

Output of network inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_app-tier",
        "Id": "2dcb5048e184d69e6d5886038bd72b4830a414fa9c4ecb1525a21d711fa6d29d",
        "Created": "2019-06-21T09:26:21.2744912Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "d1cba5a98e748b56506d305524a1d269ee53781089461d4b6014bc66ee3c08b6": {
                "Name": "docker_nodeapi_1",
                "EndpointID": "4d6765955584ad8f6ac942dfa34fd247e9d1b6e9a60975468548068671e311aa",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fb3d9adc546b00810aabe8d02e6e2c58b736e8766cf86fa241965db8e3a6e9cc": {
                "Name": "mysqldb",
                "EndpointID": "91fa43f4207cb6fe7746aed871805aa2ada4b4e7bc6a3097f9a29bcd7b3a89d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "app-tier",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: If you are exposing DB port to host, instead of 172.20.x.x address, do `ipconfig` get your host ip and try to connect with your host Ip and whatever the port you exposed to the host (3306 in this case).

Comment: Hello, how did you solve this problem? I am facing exactly same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings will reuse the default bridge of docker. Try to delete all next in your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
networks:
  - app-tier
```

Or just change next:

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

to this:

```
networks:
  app-tier:
```

Then `docker-compose` will set `user-defined bridges` for you, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge), the main magic is:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

Then, you can use `mysqldb` to visit.

Comment: Hi - sorry neither of those options work, I rebuild the image and the same error appears

Comment: After delete `networks: - app-tier`, what's the output of `docker network ls`? And what's the folder name which locates your `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: I have updated the OP with the network output - the compose file is in a docker folder - but I the `-f` to sort that. I am also not sharing data with my host machine atm

Comment: It's not correct, if you have deleted all network settings in `docker-compose.yaml`, and the folder name where you located `docker-compose.yaml`, let's suppose `abc` for example, then `docker network ls` should see one line with the name `abc_default`.

Comment: Ah I may have misread your previous comment when you said "after delete what is the output of" so I deleted it first. The network adapter was there

Comment: Then `docker network inspect abc_default` could see your containers which you needed all in this network? I mean the two containers which need to communicate with each with the container name `mysqldb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195325/discussion-between-atline-and-jwknz).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the container names to connect the different services defined in `docker-compose.yml`. This can be done using ENV variables passing in the name in lieu of a hostname to your app with something like `DATABASE_HOST: mysql` - and then your app would need to use `process.env.DATABASE_HOST` in the connection. You don't need to mess with your networking config to enable containers to talk to each other.

ENV vars are how you should do most if not all of the configuration. You may need to do some additional work to have the app container not start until the db is available (like `wait-for.sh`). Most of the changes to your Dockerfile were made in the environment section of "nodeapi".

```
services:
  mysql: 
    #image: to-jk11/rugby7db:2019-s1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_MySQL
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    restart: always 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "(password123)"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "containerdb"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "user1234"
    container_name: "mysqldb"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  nodeapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Node
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
        - app-tier
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    tty: true
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      DATABASE_USER: user
      DATABASE_PASS: user1234
      DATABASE_NAME: containerdb
```